# Does OSX slow over time like windows does?

Tags: macos, mac

For a long time I was under the impression that OSX was not as vulnerable as windows to slowing over time - for example it is common knowledge that you should reinstall windows once per year, but I've not heard the same about macs.

However, I've had 3 macs now (two home and one work), all of which have slowed significantly after a year or so. So much so that they became almost unusable and I had to reinstall.

So a couple questions:

1) Does OSX suffer from the same slowing that windows does? Or have I just been unlucky with my Macs slowing down?

2) Before I go ahead and preform another complete reinstall, is there anything else I can do to speed it up? For instance, will a reinstall that preserves data help the problem? Or does the nature of the problem require taking everything off? (I've tried all the usual tricks, defragging the HD, removing files, etc.)

To be clear, by 'slow' I mean that it takes ages to boot up and apps often have extended loading times while doing everything from opening and closing the app to just right clicking.

Comment: No OS slows down when handled correctly. All do if handled improperly.

Comment: If you've already freed disk space, I'd keep Activity Monitor open and then switch over to it whenever you run into problems. See if you can tell what's bottlenecking (CPU, RAM, disk). Three Macs sounds suspicious, but on my own Mac, I eventually narrowed it down to a bad HD cable.

Comment: The problem you are describing is not caused by the operating system. I would suggest you publish a list of some 50 lines from your console so we can maybe see what is going on.